# c++ custom array browsable in Visual Studio watch window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I would like to create an array like class in C++. Among other reasons, because I want an array with custom malloc. This may seem simple enough, but I want to use it like an usual array, meaning:

```
- initialization like   arr foo[10];   or   arr bla[] = {2, 3};
- more important, I want to be able to see its members in Visual Studio watch window.
```

I mean in the Visual Studio watch window you just click on left of an array and it's content is expanded and all members are shown. For the watch part I'm interested in both kind of solutions: a clever designed class and an add-on for Visual Studio.

Comment: c++ has a class like this. It is a `std::vector` and the visual studio watch window can already view it's elements ...

Comment: @FantasticMrFox That comment completely foregoes the reasons mentioned in the question for not using it.

Comment: You want to create a **visualizer** for your class (a `"*.natvis"` file) and add it to Visual Studio's collection, which is going to be somewhere like `%VSINSTALLPREFIX%\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\`. I haven't done this myself, and our code is full of proprietary stuff I can't share,  but this info might be enough to help you search for examples.

Comment: @MaxLanghof What reasons? Custom malloc? Use an allocator. Initialization like `arr bla[] = {2, 3};`? `std::vector` has that and more. If it's something in the *amoung other reasons* then how did you know :O !?

Comment: The natvis documentation can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2017

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I know that, but just saying "use `std::vector`" without any further justification when the answer already mentioned not wanting to use it is not going to convince the asker.

Comment: @MaxLanghof The OP doesn't say *I don't want to use a `std::vector`* anywhere in the question. I figured maybe the OP didn't know about `std::vector` and has perhaps being using raw arrays and struggling to look at them in the watch window ...

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Ok, fair point, I might have been reading too much into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.natvis` files for this purpose. Either you can define the visualization via pattern-matching or via a custom debug visualization application:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Writing-graphical-debugger-a17e3d75

However, if you want an "array with custom malloc", you can leverage the [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) support in `std::vector`.

Comment: As I said, malloc is not the only thing. And I'm interested in other custom containers, too. But should I understand that is not possible to make initialization work like v[3] or v[] = {...}? I thought maybe operator overloading, but how?

Comment: Well so far you have not come up with an incentive that `std::vector` does not fulfill. If it's not the only thing, what are the other things? "Other containers" in the standard library also have allocator support, so this is not a good reason either. And please restrict your question to one thing at a time. If the title is "can custom arrays be browsable in Visual Studio watch window", then "is it possible to make initialization work like [...]" is _definitely_ off-topic.